# Flex items from navigationbar pushing down whole page when hovering over another flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

So when I hover over the London flex item, the other flex items below push down the whole page. I want the flex items that drop down to instead overlay the content on the page.

I did not want o use a list because that seemed to be more annoying and I thought using flexbox would be easier and better. Though now I may have to go back to using a list.

I cant seem to find a solution and I dont know how to fix it. Any help or advice would be appriciated! (I'm also faily new to coding)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.container { 
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 67px);
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
}
.navbar a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.active-dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.active-dropdown > .dropdown-sub{
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column; /* or row */
}
.active-dropdown:hover > .dropdown-sub {
    display: flex;
}
.active-dropdown:hover > .dropdown-sub  > .dropdown-option:hover{
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
.active-dropdown a{
    display: block;
    background-color: #04AA6D !important;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.active-dropdown a:hover {
    color: white;
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.main {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.londontxt {
    flex: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.pic {
    flex: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.pic img {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
.pic h2 {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>City</title>
    <link href="london.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>City Gallery</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="active-dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-title"><a href="london.html">London</a></div>
                <div class="dropdown-sub">
                    <div class="dropdown-option">option 1</div>
                    <div class="dropdown-option">option 2</div>
                    <div class="dropdown-option">option 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a style="align-self: flex-start" href="#">Paris</a>
            <a style="align-self: flex-start" href="#">Tokyo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="londontxt">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous 
                city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
                <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its
                history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <h2>Bild 1</h2>
                <img src="londonbridge.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <h2>Bild 2</h2>
                <img src="londonbigben.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Copyright © 2022 Johannes</footer>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to position the `.dropdown-sub` properly. Kindly add this CSS to your code.

```
.active-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.active-dropdown > .dropdown-sub{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are an absolute legend! But what does the position: relative; and posotion: absolute; actually do?

Comment: You can read more about positions [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)